# App that actively analyzes runs and gives training advice

Tags: android, sport

I would expect at least some running apps to try and analyze running speeds and give (intelligent) advice, either post-fact ("you have a 4 day gap in your weekly running schedule, this is detrimental to your training", "your speed decreases significantly towards the end of your run, you should try starting at a slower pace", etc.) or during the run ("you should pause now for *x* minutes", "you should increase your speed", "sprint for 2 minutes" etc.).

### Specifics:

- OS: Android (or something that can import data from an Android app)
- No specific requirements as far as the specific advice that is generated, as I have been unable to find any apps at all doing this.

Answer (score -1):

Since day 1 in my running routines I have been using "RunKeeper" (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fitnesskeeper.runkeeper.pro&hl=en) I use it on my iPhone but just checking reviews on Google Play I think is great on Android too.

It does not do all you are asking but quite close. You should give it a try!